# Where is the submit a post option in the visual studio developer community forum?

Tags: forums

Where is the submit a post option in the visual studio developer community forum?

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/Setup.html?sort=active

I can't see the option

Here are two screenshots showing what I see there.

I have tried ctrl-f   new, and I can't see the option.

[image]

...................................................................

[image]

I tried clicking "Report a problem" then "Would you like to know more?"  and it says that I should do a search and then see an option below that says "Can't find an existing problem that meets your criteria? Report a new problem""  But I don't see any such option.

Suppose I search for c++ winforms missing 2015 then all I get is this at the bottom of my search results

[image]

Comment: I just tried it now.  You have to be logged in to your Microsoft account, and it seems like you can only do it through the web interface via choosing C++ under Report a Problem (for Visual Studio issues, they apparently want you to report them using a button within the VS installer or in VS itself for 2017).

Comment: Parenthetically, this may be helpful: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30695/ccli-gone.html :)

Comment: @jonsca  thanks. Regarding the installer, do you know if VS 2015 has an option? I see https://i.imgur.com/JkYorr5.png    and https://i.imgur.com/lje76X0.png   my installer is VS 2015 update 1, though it let me update VS 2015 to update 3.

Comment: No clue, unfortunately.  I don't have a 2015 installer handy to check.  The installation issue might be something that [SO] can handle, though.